# Java: invoking methods in main program, but getting an error

Tags: java, methods

I'm just learning Java and am practicing creating methods and then invoking them in my main program.  To practice this I created a simple program that's supposed to gather data from a prospective horse rider.

Here is the main application:

```
public class CompleteApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TaskOne weight1 = new TaskOne();
    TaskTwo nameagehealth1 = new TaskTwo();
    TaskThree phoneaddress1 = new TaskThree();

    if (weight1.Weight() < 250) {
      nameagehealth1.NameAgeHealth();
      phoneaddress1.AddressPhone();
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Thanks for checking!");
    }
  }
}
```

I've created three separate classes to do different tasks.  Here is the class that's having prompting the error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TaskThree {

  static void AddressPhone() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please tell me your address: ");
    String address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please tell me your phone number: ");
    int phone = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You said your address is " + address + " and your phone is " + phone + ".");

    System.out.println("Thank you for the information, we'll be in touch soon to schedule your ride.");
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "3037201234"
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at TaskThree.AddressPhone(TaskThree.java:10)
at CompleteApp.main(CompleteApp.java:13)
```

It seems to indicate that the error is in the phone number and that is being read as a String, yet I made it an integer.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.  Also, how would I handle it if a user entered their phone number like this: 303-720-1234 vs 3037201234?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: What's the biggest value that can fit into an `int`? Why store a phone number as an `int`?

Answer (score 2):

Since it can't be stored as an int due to the length as Sibbo mentioned, and you're concerned about formatting then you should store it as a String. If you have to do any type of checking to make sure the user inputs data in the correct format (either 1234567890 or 123-456-7890) then you should look into regular expressions. If you run a regular expression on your string then you will be able to get a boolean result to tell you whether or not it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Why not represent the phone number as a String and use scanner.next()? As mentioned before, when a phonenumber start with a 0 this zero would be removed if you use anything other than String, so I think it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I read that parsing it to a `Long` works for you. I would strongly recommend using a `String` though, for several reasons:

1. Phone numbers with leading zeroes (like international phone numbers). Integers and Longs 'trim' leading zeroes, rendering your phone numbers useless.
2. If you want to do some extra stuff when presenting your phone numbers (like adding dashes or anything), you will have to parse your Integer/Long back to a String and do your representation magic anyway.
3. As you just found out, not every phone number can be stored in a 32-bit Integer, but you already worked around that using a Long.

There are probably more reasons for this, but these 2 come to mind.

Comment: Excellent thoughts.  Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: So.. in any case where a user has the choice of inputting data in numbers or words, should I choose a String?  Seems to make the most sense.  Is there a downfall to that?

Comment: Not really, as long as you remember to do some form of parsing to prevent people from adding alphanumeric characters in your phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The `int` data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). Your input value is out of the range of `int`.
You should store phone number as `String` rather than `int`. If you want to handle numbers like `303-720-1234`, parse it as string, remove the `-` character and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

The input `3037201234` is too large to be represented as an `int`, so it cannot be parsed as an `int`.

Integers in Java range from `−2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

Comment: Apart from this, never store phone numbers as integers. What if your phone number starts with a 0 (or multiple zeroes, say for international phone numbers)? If you use an integer, the leading zeroes will be 'trimmed' and your phone number will not be correct anymore.

Comment: I changed it to a long and still no dice.

Comment: I'd probably use `String`.

Comment: Have you tried the `nextLong()` method? Just changing the type of `phone` won't fix it.

Comment: Ah.. I forgot to switch the int to long further down in my code.  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using int for variable phone declare it as long and instead of input.nextInt() use method input.nextLong(). I think this will solve your problem.